# InetAddress: метод getByAddress() принимает не все ip?

Tags: java

В классе `InetAddress` есть метод `getByAddress`,который принимает на вход массив байтов, содержащий `IPv4` или `IPv6`. Но в Java максимально значение `byte` - `128`, то есть некоторые адреса передать не удастся, например на

```
InetAddress host = InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[]{192, 168, 0, 1});
```

будет ругаться, так как `192` и `168` не входят в диапазон значений `byte`.

То есть получается, что можно передать далеко не все адреса? Или я что-то не так понимаю?

Comment: Метод принимает именно что массив байтов, а не массив элементов типа Byte. А раз тип byte знаковый, то не входящие абы в диапазон значения надо задавать отрицательными. И максимальное значение не 128, а на единичку меньше.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Классы для работы с IP воспринимают переданные байты как набор битов, а не как знаковые значения типа `byte`. Поэтому чтобы передать значения выходящие за пределы диапазона достаточно привести их к `byte`:

```
InetAddress host = InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[]{(byte) 192, (byte) 168, (byte) 0, (byte) 1});
```

Значения от 128 до 255 будут приведены к отрицательным значениям от -1 до -128.

В качестве альтернативы можно использовать [метод, принимающий строку](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByName(java.lang.String)):

```
InetAddress host = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.0.1");
```